# How to rotate player to face mouse on canvas?

Tags: javascript, html-canvas

I'm building a basic game using plain javascript and I am trying to rotate my object to follow my mouse.

I've tried getting the client's mouse X and Y then subtracting the canvas width and height divided by two. Then taking those values and inputing it into `Math.atan2()`. However, I feel the issue may be in my transform and rotate. The code bellow is what I've tried.

```
WIDTH = c.height;
HEIGHT = c.width;
document.onmousemove = function(ve){
            let cX = -c.width / 2;
            let cY = -c.height / 2;
            let x = ve.offsetX;
            let y = ve.offsetY;
            var rX = cX + x - 8;
            var rY = cY + y - 8;
            player.angle = Math.atan2(rX, rY) / Math.PI * 180;
        }
function update(){
                        var now = Date.now();
                        dt = now - lastUpdate;
                        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);
                        ctx.rotate(player.angle + 10);
                        drawCircle(player.x, player.y, 20, 0, 180, "red");
                        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
setInterval(update, dt/10000);
```

The player spins around my mouse in wide circles with no apparent pattern.
Here's a gif showing what's happening.
https://gyazo.com/006c99879ecf219791d059de14d98b74

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform the `(0;0)` position of the canvas so that it lies on the center of the player, then after rotating it, draw the player at `(0; 0)`. This is required, because every rotation gets applied around the origin.

Comment: So was that what was the weird rotation?

Comment: @Ameer yes, you don't draw the player to (0; 0)

Comment: Alrighty I'll try that out asap and get back to you